# how to pass command line parameter containing '<' to 'exec'

Tags: tcl

```
$ date > '< abcd'
$ cat '< abcd'
<something>
$ tclsh8.5
% exec cat {< abcd}
couldn't read file " abcd": no such file or directory
```

whoops. This is due to the the specification of 'exec'.

> If an arg (or pair of args) has one of the forms described below then it is used by exec to control the flow of input and output among the subprocess(es). Such arguments will not be passed to the subprocess(es). In forms such as “< fileName”, fileName may either be in a separate argument from “<” or in the same argument with no intervening space".

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: To close the loop on this one: it seems to be a limitation of 'exec' that it can't pass along an argument that begins with '<' to the downstream program. I patched my copy of 'exec' to require that the redirection operator be a separate word. Hence cat < abcd will cause redirection, but cat {< abcd} will pass on the quoted-string as is downstream. The new limitation will be that 'exec' can't pass along a bare '<' as an argument. But I don't have that requirement yet :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the value have to be passed as an argument? If not, you can use something like this:

```
set strToPass "< foo"
exec someProgram << $strToPass
```

For filenames, you can (almost always) pass the fully qualified name instead. The fully qualified name can be obtained with `file normalize`:

```
exec someProgram [file normalize "< foo"]       ;# Odd filename!
```

But if you *need* to pass in an argument where `<` (or `>`) is the first character, you're stuck. The `exec` command always consumes such arguments as redirections; unlike with the Unix shell, you can't just use quoting to work around it.

But you can use a helper program. Thus, on Unix you can do this:

```
exec /bin/sh -c "exec someProgram \"$strToPass\""
```

<sup>(The subprogram just replaces itself with what you want to run passing in the argument you really wanted. You might need to use `string map` or `regsub` to put backslashes in front of problematic metacharacters.)</sup>

On Windows, you have to write a batch file and run that, which has a lot of caveats and nasty side issues, especially for GUI applications.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I'm stuck if I want to pass an argument starting with '<'. Yeah, I was going to either do a mix of the approaches above, or patch my copy of Tcl (I have the ability to package an interpreter with my program).

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution: ensure the word does not *begin* with the redirection character:

```
exec cat "./< abcd"
```

One slightly more complex:

```
exec sh -c {cat '< abcd'}

# also
set f {< abcd}
exec sh -c "cat '$f'"
```

This [page on the Tcl Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1353) talks about the issue a bit.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for a decent solution to this problem and the wiki link, but the 'cat' command in my case was only for illustrative purposes. 'echo' would have been a better analog to what I am really doing. I want to pass the string as-is to the downstream program.

Comment: Can you not wrap the cmd in `sh -c "..."`? That puts the `<` symbol out of reach of exec.

Comment: yes, I can. But then I may have to descend into quoting hell. I'm trying hard to avoid doing that. :) It really does look like Tcl's exec can't pass an argument that starts with '<' to a downstream program.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
% exec {cat < abcd}
```

Comment: sorry, doesn't work (as expected). It tries to find program called 'cat < abcd'. The exact err is:

    couldn't execute "cat < abcd": no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Try:

set myfile "< abcd"

exec cat $myfile

Comment: Doesn't work (I'd actually tried this, but I pasted your commands into the prompt anyway).

Comment: I'm not at my pc so I can't try it. Try escaping the < with a backslash.

Comment: That definitely won't work; if `exec` sees the `<` at the start of a word it is a redirection, if it isn't at the start, it won't be at the start of an argument. This is a known misfeature of Tcl.

Comment: @Donal, thank for the info. I was just guessing whilst on my phone :-)