# tcl, grep and the greater than sign

Tags: grep, tcl

I am trying to grep for a string that contains a greater than sign in tcl.
What I tried so far:

```
grep -orI -- {\> somestring} dir
```

but that does not appear to work.

Then I tried looking for the greater than sign only:

```
grep -orI -- \> dir
```

That did not work..

Comment: grep is not a Tcl command. So this must be part of an exec statement or some custom procedure in your program which you should include. If it is an exec call, you must mind the quoting as > is used to indicate redirection in Tcl exec commands. Why not read the file and use the Tcl regexp command?

Comment: I simply want to count instances of a specific ip address prefixed by a `>` sign in a huge file. Using grep with `wc -l` was the first thing that came to mind and then I got curious as to why it was not working. After that I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051309/how-to-pass-command-line-parameter-containing-to-exec) which solved the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do stuff to ensure that `>` is not the first character of a word in the exec cmd: for example, using otherwise needless capturing parentheses

```
$ tclsh
% exec cat ./afile
line1
line2 > somestring
line3
% exec grep -orI {> somestring} .
[waits for me to hit ctrl-d]
child process exited abnormally
% exec grep -orI {\(> somestring\)} .
./afile:> somestring
```

Comment: Many thanks! This seems to work perfectly. I never would have thought to resolve it this way. Thank you, this really helps extend my understanding of tcl and its workarounds. The underlying rule here is that `>` Can be avoided as a redirection by the use of `(` `)` to make the regular expression start with a different character?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question and answer:
[how to pass command line parameter containing '<' to 'exec'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051309/how-to-pass-command-line-parameter-containing-to-exec)

I realized that exec and `>` are not friends in tcl. I will find a creative way to overcome this or use another tool for this task.

Comment: Strictly, they're _too_ friendly; `exec`'s syntax sucks (and yeah, we know it does but don't want to break the large number of existing scripts that use it).

Answer (score 0):

eval is your friend:

```
set cmd "grep this someFile.txt > outputfile.txt"
eval $cmd
```

Comment: Thanks but no I'm looking for `>` not using it for redirection. ;)

Comment: oops!  well, I still think eval should work , but I don't have solution yet.

Comment: eval did not work for that. :) what works here is using brackets like Glen J. suggested. :) Eval does let you have more power in editing the command before your execute it.